# VBA Multilevel Row Grouping

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

I found a macro in Reddit forum ( https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/vyzk5x/vba_multilevel_row_grouping/ ) which is exactly what I was looking for and that works fine.

```
Sub GroupingTest()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim row_grp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Feuil4")
    
    ws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove
    
    'lrow = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lrow = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
    
    For i = 2 To lrow - 1
        If ws.Cells(i, 54).Value < ws.Cells(i + 1, 54).Value Then
            If i + 1 = lrow Then
                ws.Rows(i + 1).Group
            End If
            For j = i + 2 To lrow
                If ws.Cells(i, 54).Value = ws.Cells(j, 54).Value Or ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = 0 Then
                    ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & j - 1).Group
                    Exit For
                ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 54).Value > ws.Cells(j, 54).Value Then
                    Exit For
                ElseIf j = lrow Then
                    ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & j).Group
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

However, it breaks at line 763, I guess because I reach the 8th level.
My database has at least 10 levels. How can I manage these levels up to 8th?
Thx in advance.

[image: vba console]
[image: result of grouping]

Comment: You can group only 8 levels in Excel. Using VBA doesn't change that limitation.